# Detect if browser is waiting for media permission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in **javascript** to check if Browser(Any Browser) is waiting for user to **Allow** permission for **Microphone** or **Camera**?

[image]

**Note:-** Based on this, I want to determine if media permission was already saved. i.e. if permission is saved then the popup will not appear.

**EDIT**

```
MEDIA = ( navigator.webkitGetUserMedia     ||
          navigator.mozGetUserMedia        ||
          navigator.msGetUserMedia         ||
          navigator.getUserMedia           );

get_user_media: function() {
  jQuery("instruction_image_id").show();

  (MEDIA.bind(navigator))(
    {audio: true, video: false},
    media_success(),
    media_error()
  );
}

media_success: function() {
  jQuery("instruction_image_id").hide();
}
```

**EDIT**

**Note:-** I need a Cross Browser solution. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047056/is-it-possible-to-check-if-the-user-has-a-camera-and-microphone-and-if-the-permi)(Marked as duplicate) thread's solution works well only with Chrome.

Comment: `Based on this, I want to determine if media permission was already saved` Why do you need that?

Comment: @A.Wolff Because I want to show an image that has visual instructions that asks user to click on **Allow** and this image gets hidden in the success block of **getUserMedia**. If permissions are saved then this image fluctuates.

Comment: So you can use any kind of persistent data client side which you set the first time your user allow it (localStorage). Then check for it. But what you ask could be a XY problem in fact, not sure about it

Comment: I tried using `localStorage`, but user always has option to revoke the permissions from browser settings, then I don't know how to reset `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

The time between waiting can be checked here, see start and end of permission:

```js
// Start the permission.
navigator.getUserMedia (
  // constraints
  {
    video: true,
    audio: true
  },

  // successCallback
  function(localMediaStream) {
    // End the permission
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      // Do something with the video here.
    };
  },

  // errorCallback
  function(err) {
    if(err === PERMISSION_DENIED) {
      // Explain why you need permission and how to update the permission setting
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: @Abhi Already, is it? I don't think so, or I don't know. `:(`

Comment: I have my site in HTTPS so it saves permission for subsequent calls

Comment: @Abhi Yes, for HTTPS it already saves. So when you go through the permission process, and you get a success function, then it looks like the user has disabled and adds it for the first time.