# HTML5 API listen for changes to video and audio device permission

Tags: html

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047056/is-it-possible-to-check-if-the-user-has-a-camera-and-microphone-and-if-the-permi) demonstrates how it's possible to detect if the user has a microphone and camera enabled using HTML5.

My question: is there a way to listen for changes? For example, if the user changes the permissions for their video/audio in the browser.

I want to be able to display a message on my page that says "warning, you have disabled access to the microphone" or whatever.