# How to receive audio/video without accepting the autorequest popup in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

I want to receive audio/video without accepting the permission that browser asks to access mic/cam. Is it possible?

I'm using SimpleWebRTC, my code is here:

```
// create our webrtc connection
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
    remoteVideosEl: '',
    // immediately ask for camera access
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    debug: false,
    detectSpeakingEvents: true,
    autoAdjustMic: false,
    media: {
        video: {
            frameRate: {
                max: 30
            },
            width: {
                max: 176
            },
            height: {
                max: 144
            }
        },
        audio: true
    },
});
```

1. If I delete this => **autoRequestMedia: true** or change it to false, so it doesn't ask to get permission and the result is NOTHING
   :(
2. If I leave this => **autoRequestMedia: true** to be true, so the browser asks to get permission,

   2-1: if I don't accept, the result is NOTHING :(
   2-2: if I accept, it works :)

So my problem is how I can receive(not send) data(audio/video) without accepting that permission popup or even set that autoRequestMedia to false and receive data?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicating your [own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435103/can-i-receive-video-without-giving-permission-to-browser-to-use-my-camera-in-sim)? You are telling simplewebrtc that you want media which means it will wait until it gets it.

Comment: My question: Why we can't receive data(audio/video) without connecting mic/cam and accepting that permission popup?

Comment: Because using the mic/cam from a webpage requires permission from the user...

Comment: @Kevin I know, but I don't want to use it for sending but receiving.

Comment: The permission prompt comes when calling getUserMedia, SimpleWebRTC seems to call that quite a lot. If you want more control over this you'll have to use WebRTC and manage the media yourself instead of using SimpleWebRTC.

Comment: @Kevin OK could you help me in WebRTC just in this specific problem I have?

Comment: With WebRTC itself it's easy, just don't call getUserMedia. That means you won't be able to create a local media stream, so you can't add a local stream to the peerconnection, but other than that there shouldn't be any significant difference with a regular WebRTC app.

Comment: Thanks dear Kevin :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser restriction. Otherwise any application could open your devices silently in the background and listen for you.

However it is possible to call getUserMedia() only once at your app start (this is where the popups appears) and reuse that onward everywhere thus preventing any additional popups at incoming audio/video.